# USB Mass Storage device communication in Windows UWP desktop application

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, desktop-application

I am developing a Windows desktop application which communicates with a fingerprint device with their provided .dll library. I developed a complete functioning application in WPF application. But while upgrading the application to UWP application it doesn't communicate with device where it works fine in WPF application. I added device capabilities with Vendor and Product ID in App manifest but still no progress. What is different in WPF and UWP in communicating with USB Mass Storage modules from the application?

Comment: How did you upgrade the WPF application to UWP app?

Comment: Please try the official [CustomUsbDeviceAccess](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess) sample to see if it does work.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I didn't used any tool. I created it from scratch again in UWP. And I have already tried those samples. That didn't worked for me. I guess it is related to the USB permission for UWP apps. But adding device capabilities with Vendor and Product ID didn't solved the issue.

Comment: First, you need to check if the 'provided .dll library' is using the supported APIs in UWP. See [Win32 and COM APIs for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps). Second, have you followed my suggestion to try the [CustomUsbDeviceAccess](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess) sample.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. That didn't work. Provided .dll doesn't work in UWP like it works on WPF. I am planning to try creating byte packets as there given refference. If it doesn't work, I may have to move to WPF format.

Comment: The CustomUsbDeviceAccess sample shows how to access USB devices from UWP. When you say that they "didn't work" please be more specific. Did you update the fingerprint device's DLL to use the UWP USB APIs? My guess is that it is still using Win32 APIs that are not supported in UWP.

Comment: The .dll worked because the dll file returns specific value for events. On this case it says communication error @RaymondChen

Comment: Your response is confusing. First you say that the DLL worked, then you say that it doesn't. I'm guessing that you mean it worked in the WPF app, but not the UWP app. That's probably because the DLL needs to be updated to communicate with the USB device in a UWP-compatible way.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But the vendor are not interested on updating the .dll so I am now working in WPF format. Thanks for your response.